# How to get list in alert dialog?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-alertdialog

I want to set an alert dialog with list of titles. I have database and table of time table in that.

Time table has column of title. I want to get the list of titles from time table.

I tried some code but it's not working. I have created query in TimeTableHelper to get list of table. But I don't know how to put it in alert dialog.

Can anyone help please?

```
selectTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TimeTableHelper th = new TimeTableHelper(getApplicationContext());
            List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>(th.getTitle());

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEventActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
```

I am getting error can not resolve constructor ArrayAdapter if I try to add list in this.

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables);

How t do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass activity context but inside `onClick` method `this` means the `onClickListener` interface.

Change

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables);
```

to

```
// Replace MyActivity with the activity you are currently in or getActivity() if inside a fragment
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tables);
```

Comment: the MyActivity.this is a bad idea, the activity is simply available from "getActivity()" method.

Comment: @McflyDroid: Really? What if the code is inside an activity?

Comment: A bad idea to my mind doing this in an activity. But if you want just do it =)

Comment: It's never a bad idea. Just a bad thought that you should always do this in a fragment.